# How to include some data and other data in SQL conditioned to date?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have this query, that selects the users, some data, with some filters (such as group that they are in and stuff) and with them the amount they produced (in $) last month (get the last existing record from last month, using `MAX(created_date)`), for a management platform, which shows how much they produced this month and at the previous (`us.amount_produced` and `up.amount_produced last_month_amount`).

The problem is that it doesn't select users that are new (that haven´t produced any amount last month), and I need those to return too.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

(I was thinking about doing a JOIN or even two queries, but I´m sure about the best approach)

**Note** by examples below that the user #3 didnt have any logs at the User_Performance table before February, he was created on february. So the query below won't return him (i need it to return him)

User table structure:

```
Users
id       email            login    amount_produced   created_date
---------------------------------------------
1        foo@bar.com      foo      1000              2019-12-20 22:30:01
2        jack@gmail.com   jack     0                 2019-12-20 22:30:01
3        john@gmail.com   john     2000              2020-02-01 00:00:01
```

User_Group_Config table structure:

```
User_Group_Config
user_id       group_id
---------------------------------------------
   1            4  
   2            1
   3            4
```

User_Performance table structure **this table is a log table that a job inserts data every hour, calculating users productivity and logging**:

```
Users
user_id       amount_produced     created_date
---------------------------------------------
1                   500           2020-01-31 22:30:01
2                   0             2020-01-31 22:30:01
1                   500           2020-01-31 23:30:01
2                   0             2020-01-31 23:30:01
1                   1000          2020-02-01 00:30:01
2                   0             2020-02-01 00:30:01
3                   0             2020-02-01 00:30:01
```

```
SELECT 
    us.id,
    us.email,
    us.login,
    ugc.group_id,
    up.user_id,
    up.amount_produced last_month_amount
FROM
    db.User_Performance AS up,
    db.User_Group_Config ugc,
    db.User AS us
WHERE
    created_date IN (SELECT 
            MAX(created_date)
        FROM
            User_Performance
        WHERE
            /* Here it filters only users that have data last month, I need these AND the ones that have no data to return zero here or null or undefined at this row)*/
            MONTH(created_date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
        GROUP BY user_id)
        AND ugc.group_id = 4
        AND up.user_id = ugc.user_id
        AND us.id = up.user_id;
```

**Desired Results** (note that user #2 wasn´t selected since his group_id is #1

```
Results 
                                   (current month)   (previous month)
id       email            login    amount_produced   last_month_amount
---------------------------------------------
1        foo@bar.com      foo      1000              500
3        john@gmail.com   john     0                 null or 0
```

Comment: To receive the records which have no matched records in slave tables you must use left joining.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would very much clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Done @GordonLinoff, sample data inserted and desired results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using this, with subquery and JOIN (not the best solution, but a solution):

```
SELECT 
    us.id,
    us.email,
    us.login,
    ugc.group_id,
    us.amount_produced,
    (
        SELECT
            perf.amount_produced
        FROM
            User_Performance perf
        WHERE
            perf.user_id = us.id AND
            perf.created_date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00') and CONCAT(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), " 23:59:59")
        ORDER BY
            perf.created_date DESC
            LIMIT 1
    ) as amount_produced_last_month
FROM
    User AS us
INNER JOIN
    User_Group_Config ugc ON ugc.user_id = us.id
WHERE
    ugc.group_id = 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

Test

```
SELECT 
    us.id,
    us.contact_phone,
    us.email,
    us.first_name,
    us.last_name,
    us.login,
    ugc.group_id,
    us.create_date,
    us.expire_date,
    us.profile_photo,
    us.dashboard_enabled,
    us.general_rating,
    us.rework_rating,
    us.amount_produced,
    us.amount_spent,
    up.user_id,
    up.amount_produced last_month_amount
FROM db.User_Performance AS up
LEFT JOIN db.User_Group_Config ugc ON up.user_id = ugc.user_id AND ugc.group_id = 4
LEFT JOIN db.User us ON us.id = up.user_id
WHERE
    up.created_date IN (SELECT 
            MAX(created_date)
        FROM
            User_Performance
        WHERE
            /* Here it filters only users that have data last month, I need these AND the ones that have no data to return zero here or null or undefined at this row)*/
            MONTH(created_date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
        GROUP BY user_id);
```

Comment: That didn´t do the trick. It returned people that the group_id is not 4 and didn´t return the ones I wanted. I'll try to edit the question and put some sample data to clarify the matter, thanks Akina